# error with using mysqli_real_escape_string on OOP

Tags: php, oop

I am getting these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xxx\database.php on line 44
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xxx\database.php on line 44
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xxx\database.php on line 31

I've got my database connections connected correctly. I get these errors when I run my files as below:

```
//database.php
<?php

require_once ("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

private $connection;

function _construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
}

public function open_connection() {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed:" .
                mysqli_connect_error() .
                "( " . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    } 
}

public function close_connection() {
    if (isset($this->connection)) {
        mysqli_close($this->connnection);
        unset($this->connection);
    }
}

public function query($sql) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);        <<line 31
    $this->confirm_query($result);
    return $result;
}

private function confirm_query($result) {
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
}

public function escape_value($string) {
    
    $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);   <<line 44
    return $escaped_string;
}

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();
$db =& $database;
?>
```

running for *'user.php'*

```
public static function authenticate($email="", $password="") {
        global $database;
        $email = $database->escape_value($email);
        $password = $database->escape_value($password);

        /*SQL statements*/
}
```

*'config.php'*

```
<?php
// Database Constants
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost:3306");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "username");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "password");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "databasename");
?>
```

what exactly is wrong?

Comment: do `var_dump($database); die;` before you try to escape the value.  You'll be able to see what the value of your connection is.

Comment: can you show us the config.php file?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond after adding `var_dump($database)` i've gotten back `object(MySQLDatabase)#2 (1) { ["connection":"MySQLDatabase":private]=> NULL }` which i do not fully understand it's meaning

Comment: NULL either means you didn't initialize or there was an error with the connection.  I would recommend using the Object Oriented approach to using mysqli to avoid that.  I'm fairly certain the function mysql_error_no requires the first parameter to be the connection.  Remove the var_dump and die commands, and you can add it elsewhere to see the actual value of the variable at that moment in time.